# Given a set of letters in a string how to get remaining letters in the string in python

Tags: python

I have a String like 'LETTER' now i have another string "LTR" when the string is checked with the previous one the remaining letters are "ETE" how can  i extract this from the main string in python. The order of the letters doesn't matter any way we should get the remaining letters

Comment: sorry i will update the question

Comment: The constraints of your problem are not at all clear. What, for example, would the result be if you had TLR instead of LTR? Would it be "ETE" or would it be "TE"?

Comment: @user1275375 does the order matters, will `EET` do it for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209800/difference-between-two-strings-in-python-php

This post might help.

Answer (score 2):

use `ndiff()` from [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.ndiff) library:

```
>>> from difflib import *
>>> list(ndiff("LETTER","LTR"))
['  L', '- E', '  T', '- T', '- E', '  R']

#so filter out letters which doesn't have '-'

>>> ''.join(x.strip('-').strip() for x in filter(lambda x:'-' in x,ndiff("LETTER","LTR")))
'ETE'

>>> ''.join(x.strip('-').strip() for x in filter(lambda x:'-' in x,ndiff("stack","tc")))
'sak'
```

you can use `Counter()`, incase if the order of letters doesn't matter:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> str1="LETTER"
>>> str2="LTR"
>>> c=Counter(str1)-Counter(str2)
>>> c
Counter({'E': 2, 'T': 1})
>>> ''.join(x*c[x] for x in c)
'EET
```

Comment: I thought of this too, but it loses the order.

Comment: @DSM yeah! I was worried about ordered too, just asked the OP whether he's concerned about the order or not.

Comment: @DSM `ndiff()` from `difflib` can be used for this, and it preserves the order too.

Answer (score 2):

Popular question:-) I think this is a very readable one:

```
s=list("LETTER")                                  
p=list("LTR")                                         
while p: s.remove(p.pop())
```

Now

```
print("".join(s))
```

prints "ETE"

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = "LETTER"
>>> for c in "LTR":
...     if c in x:
...        p = x.find(c)
...        if p < len(x)-1:
...           x = x[:p]+x[p+1:]
...        else:
...           x = x[:p]
...
>>> x
'ETE'
```

Comment: It should be noted that if "LTR" were instead, "LTRxzy" an exception will be thrown at `index()`

Comment: naw it checks if `c in x` first...  but edited to use find instead of index all the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly straightforward and readable solution that correctly preserves the ordering and duplicates of the input string:

```
def omit(s, discard):
    discard = list(discard)
    for c in s:
        if c not in discard:
            yield c
        else:
            discard.remove(c)

>>> ''.join(omit('LETTER', 'LTR'))
'ETE'
```

Comment: This is pretty good, but using a set for the second argument won't work in the case you want to discard, for example, "LETT"

Comment: this is better than my answer i think

Comment: Couldn't you simply replace `set` with `list`?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/env python

def str_diff(s, rem):
    for x in rem:
        pos = s.find(x)
        if pos >= 0: s = s[:pos] + s[pos+1:]

    return s

print str_diff("LETTER", "LTR")    # ETE
print str_diff("LETTER", "LTTR")   # EE
print str_diff("LETTER", "LTRxyz") # ETE
```

This seems to do what you want to do.  It preserves original ordering, works for multiples of the same letter in the "removal set", and doesn't barf if the "removal set" includes a character not in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = "LETTER"
>>> r = "LTR"
>>> y = x
>>> for c in r:
...     y = y.replace(c, '', 1)
... 
>>> y
'ETE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def remaining(my_string, my_string_2):
    output = ""

    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(my_string) and j < len(my_string_2):
        if my_string[i] != my_string_2[j]:
            output += my_string[i]
        else:    
            j += 1
        i+=1
    if i < len(my_string):
        output+=my_string[i:len(my_string)]

    return output

result = remaining("LETTER", "LTR")

print result
```

Returns 'ETE'

Answer (score 0):

```
l1='LETTER'
l2='LTR'
occur=[]
for i in range(0,len(l1)):
    if l1[i] in occur:
        print l1[i]

    if l1[i] in l2:
        occur.append(l1[i])
    else:
        print l1[i]
```

Comment: only writing the code is never a good option please let user know what is happening